# Function that converges in $L^\infty$ but not in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I know that convergence in $L^\infty$ implies convergence in $L^p$ in finite measure spaces since if it is finite then Holder's inequality will hold and this can be proven.

I am trying to think of a function that converges in $L^\infty$ but does not converge in $L^p$ for some $p$ or maybe even for all $p$?

Comment: You mean a SEQUENCE of functions, not a function.

Answer (score 2):

Find a sequence of sets $A_n$ with measure going to infinity fast enough so that the functions
$$
f_n = \frac{1}{n}\;\mathbf1_{A_n}
$$
satisfy $\|f_n\|_\infty \to 0$ but $\|f_n\|_p \to \infty$ for all $p$.

---

**added**
Let $A_n$ have measure $2^n$.  Then
$$
\|f\|_\infty = \frac{1}{n} \to 0,
\\
\|f\|_p = \left(\int_{A_n} \frac{1}{n^p}\right)^{1/p} = \frac{2^{n/p}}{n}
\to \infty .
$$

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot figure out a possible $A_n$ that would make this work?

Comment: It's seeming like this course is too advanced for you.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f_n=\frac{1}{n}1_{[0,n]}$. It converges in $L^{\infty}$ but not in $L^1$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I corrected it now.